# Changing the /dev/tty* permissions at startup

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, devices, startup

My solution (ArchLinux ARM on RaspberryPi) requires that a non-privileged user has to have access to the `/dev/ttyAMA0` port. In final implementation that user will be automatically logged in and a start-up script would be launched, but that is off-topic.

The problem is that the `/dev/ttyAMA0` port (owned by root:tty) has 0620 permissions, and though the non-privileged user is put in the tty group, the file permissions do not give him read access, and that is not good enough.

[In this thread I was told](http://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=8887) I should use `/etc/tmpfiles.d` feature to fix the permissions. However, adding a /etc/tmpfiles.d/solution.conf file with one line

```
F /dev/ttyAMA0 0660 root tty
```

does not change a thing. Perhaps I am not using the tmpfiles.d feature correctly.

Comment: That sounds like a job for udev. But `0620 root:tty` *does* give the user read access to the port, so your problem isn't the permissions, unless you meant that the user needs *write* access (which is plausible, most serial protocols require bidirectional communication).

Comment: I don't know the reasons why the default permissions to the /dev/tty* files in archlinux is rw--w----, what, to my understanding, equals 0620, and means read+write to root and write to tty group. My project indeed needs only write access but the python script fails to initialize if there is no read access, too.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have *write* access and you want *read* access. My bad, I misread your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this problem was specific to RaspberryPi, since the `/dev/ttyAMA0` serial port that's linked to the hardware GPIO pins by default is initialized for virtual console access.

I had to remove any reference to `/dev/ttyAMA0` in `/boot/cmdline.txt`, reboot, and the `/dev/ttyAMA0` now was with proper group permissions (read+write), however the group name now was `uucp`. What is not problem, of course, to put my user in that group.

Had I wanted to change the ownership of `/dev/ttyAMA0` or permissions, that could be done via editing the rule files in the `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d` directory.

Comment: If you want to change the ownership or permissions, add a rule in `/etc/lib/udev/rules.d`, don't edit the files outside `/etc`.